# jquery ajax no funciona con php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo esto en el html

```
<body>
     <div class="content">
        <label for="">User Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="user"><br>
        <input type="text" class="a"><br>
        <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>

</div>
<div class="chat">

</div>
```

en mi ajax tengo esto pero no se por que no me manda al php la variable

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".chat").load("conection.php");

$("#enviar").click(function(){
    var user = $("#username").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'conection.php',
        data: {'user': user},
        dataType :"html"
    })
    .done(function(){
        alert("listo");
    })
})
})
```

el php es simple pero no funciona no le llega lo que se envia por ajax

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
echo $user;
 ?>
```

si alguien sabe que pasa por favor necesito de urgencia, aqui les dejo una captura de imagen donde se ve que que ajax envia y el php recibe pero no imprime la variable 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste imprimir todo el $_POST con `print_r($POST);` ?? Pensar que es jQuery el que no sirve con PHP es... aventurado.

Comment: no sale nada, se ejecuta bien pero no llega al php la variable y eso no se por que se da

Comment: El objeto data puedes mandarlo como `{user: user}`

Comment: nada man, ya probé todo y no funciona

Comment: El print_r() es en el PHP, amigo. Antes de hacer nada con el POST, imprime lo que llega.

Comment: no sale nada, tienes alguna otra idea

Comment: Mira en las devTools en Network, si es que esta haciendo la petición

Comment: ya lo hice y si manda, el php es el que no recibe

Comment: has mirado de cambiar el a json `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: no vale, es como si el php no entra la variable a pesar de que ne la red si llega y el servidor da respuesta

Comment: Cuando haces una petición ajax, no se muestra en pantalla el resultado, sino que se obtiene en una variable de javascript, en tu caso se ignora porque no hay definición en function, prueba a poner .done(function(respuesta){ y luego $("body").append(respuesta); para mostrar el resultado. Fíjate que en la pantalla que adjuntas, SI se devuelve el valor pasado.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que saber que PHP es un lenguaje que funciona en servidor, y jQuery es una librería de JavaScript que funciona en el cliente (navegador web).

Dicho eso, tú envías desde jQuery una llamada a tu servidor PHP y éste la procesa. Estás enviando esa llamada usando el método "post" pero por alguna razón que no se ve en ese código, se está enviando como si el método fuese "get".

Yo he copiado tu código y lo ejecuté y funcionó correctamente.

Así entonces, deberías comprobar si ese botón id="enviar" está dentro de un form, o ejecuta alguna otra cosa al mismo tiempo. Si no estás seguro de lo que hace, puedes probar esto:

```js
$("#enviar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var user = $("#username").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'conection.php',
        data: {'user': user},
        dataType :"html"
    })
    .done(function(){
        alert("listo");
    });
});
```